# How to convert pyspark dataframe into django html table?

Tags: python, html, django, pyspark

I am very beginner in all of them.
So my HTML code looks like this -->

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-dark table-striped">
      {% for item in tnames %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">{{ item }}</th>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for values in datas %}
        <tr>
          <td scope="row"> {{ values }}</td>
        </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

code for django to get lists for html is like that -->

```
tnames = [] 
for n in df.columns: 
    tnames.append(n)

datas=[]
for i in df.collect():
   datas.append(tuple(i))
```

and output is like this
[image]

How to fix it ? Yes I am doing something wrong. So what is right way to display them correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: when you have this kind of "wrong" display,  do not hesitate to look at the generated HTML code to see if it is what you want. Write by yourself, manually, the code, compare the display and the differences between your code and the generated one. That will help you understand where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, you can convert (almost) directly from pyspark to HTML (via pandas).

```py
html_content = df.toPandas().to_html()
```

Example with a simple df :

```py
spark.range(2).toPandas().to_html()

'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>id</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>1</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

With the different options (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html#pandas-dataframe-to-html)), you can achieve exactly what you want.

---

If you want to keep your view, you need to change a little bit the code.

Remember that :

- `<tr>` is table row (1 for header, and 1 for each element of `datas`),
- `<th>` is table header (1 for each element in `tnames`)
- `<td>` is table data (1 for each element of each element of `datas` - for loop in for loop).

```py
tnames = df.columns

datas = [tuple(row) for row in df.collect()]
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-dark table-striped">
    <tr>
        {% for item in tnames %}
        <th scope="col">{{ item }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

    {% for values in datas %}
    <tr>
        {% for value in values %}
        <td scope="row"> {{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```